# BIOS Settings Greyed-out

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, passwords

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my acer aspire v3-575G. I was prompted to set a password to disable secure boot and I complied. After restarting to configure my boot order(I am dual booting) I was surprised to see that my BIOS settings are all greyed out. The only single thing I can interact with are the date and time and the user password from the security tab. Things I tried: 1.  2.   I am running out of options. Any help would be welcome.
Things I've tried:

- Enter the user password
- Enter a wrong password
- 3x then using an Unlock BIOS password(I got into BIOS but its still the same (Greyed Out Options)
- Performing a full clean reinstall of Ubuntu (I followed [this](https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/) guide).

After trying software options I went to hard reset options. So I also tried.

- Reseat the CMOS battery (5 mins - 10 mins)

Reseating CMOS only made it worse. It just changed time and disabled F12 BOOT Options)

I feel desperate and mentally exhausted.
Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is often a different BIOS password for USER and SUPERVISOR or Admin. USER allows you to access Date and time, and little else, whereas Supervisor gives you full access.

I have three suggestions for you if you're not sure about a supervisor password:

1. Use the CMOS reset jumper to clear the BIOS. The manual page can be found here: [Acer Aspire Service Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/440323/Acer-Aspire-V3-571g.html?page=205)
2. Try removing the battery for 30 minutes, rather than 5-10. There just might be a big juicy capacitor lurking around somewhere, feeding the trickle of juice needed to keep the systems alive.
3. Try updating/re-flashing the BIOS: Download from [Asus website](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/AU/content/support-product/6342?b=1)